# How to add a specific Google play Services api to Eclipse android project

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, google-oauth

i simply need  an OAuth 2.0 token to authorize requests with Google for REST APIs. so I need to import the google play service sdk. 
specifically the:

```
Google Account Login    com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0
```

I am using eclipse I only want to import the Google account login api, but there is no instructions on how to do so.

if there is no solution, how can I grab the Jar referenced in the dependencies for android studio projects  https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: check this link https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Comment: i simply need  an OAuth 2.0 token to authenticate requests to google api, not google plus sign in

Comment: time to switch to android studio perhaps ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution I guess. Try this:

1. Go to "android_sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services-identity\8.1.0\"
2. Copy "play-services-identity-8.1.0.aar" to your eclipse project's /libs directory.
3. Open "project.properties" file and add this line: android.libraries.reference.1=libs/play-services-identity-8.1.0/ and Run Application.

And if it didn't work, try setting up your project with com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0 in android studio and import/export gradle project in/for eclipse. It will most probably resolves the included dependencies automatically to work with eclipse.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the beautiful answer. But the working solution is allot more detailed than that. View the comments in this thread http://bit.ly/1LKunQF 
You can update your answer with the remaining details there or i'll create an answer with that later. Thanks again.